# Error when adding a configurable Product in Magento 1.6.1

Tags: magento

When i create a configurable product i first get the option to select configurable attributes.
After selecting the wanted configurable attributes and pressing save i can edit the new product. I also get a javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id_219a600301fb6404e4b3542db1626331_UploaderJsObject is not defined
ReferenceError: super_product_linksJsObject is not defined
```

This error stops me from adding simple products to the configurable product.
Also after saving and rediting the product i always first get the option to select the configurable attributes again.

Comment: do you use js compression? is there any extension installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given information I'm unable to reproduce the error. I'll try giving some debugging pointers. Even if they don't help, they might provide some insight into the source of the problem.

I suggest downloading the 1.6.1 source from http://www.magentocommerce.com/getmagento/1.6.1.0/magento-1.6.1.0.tar.gz and running a diff to see if a core file is modified. If yes, revert the core changes and try again.

If there is no difference, try disabling one none-core module after the other by setting the `<active>` flag in the files in app/etc/modules/*.xml to `false`, and test again until the JS exception disappears.

Be sure to clear the cache after each change (better - disable all Magento caching and JS merging during this procedure). Also be sure to clear the browser cache before each test.

Comment: YES! setting the xml to false did the trick, i only disabled them in the admin tool.THNX!